# Sandwich theorem for PDE's

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, vector-analysis, riemann-integration

If $\textbf{v}:\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,\infty]\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\textbf{u} :\mathbb{R}^n\times [0,\infty]\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n$ are vector field such that $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\textbf{v}\le \dfrac{d}{dt}\textbf{u} $$ for all $t\ge t^\prime$ show that there exist a value $k$ such that $\textbf{v}\le \textbf{u}$ for all $t\ge k\ge t^\prime$. That is if $\textbf{u}$ has more acceleration then $\textbf{v}$ it will eventually surpass $\textbf{v}$ even if $\textbf{u}< \textbf{v}$ at some time $t< t^\prime$. We might need to restrict the derivatives or functions to not be bounded. Here we interpret $$\textbf{f}\le \textbf{g} \Longleftrightarrow  f_i\le g_i, ~~~~\forall i\le n $$ I think we can choose $$k = \min\{ t: v_i(x,t)\le u_i(x,t), \forall i\le n \}$$ holds in each component which should depend on when each component passes one another because they will all pass one another at different times.

Comment: What does it mean for one vector field to be $\leq$ another?

Comment: You still have to argue why $k$ is finite.

Comment: @stange each component $u_i$ should pass $v_i$ at some time $t_i$. We need the largest of these values actually

Comment: Yes, I know. But why is $k$ finite?

Comment: @stange because it have to occur at some finite time. It can't take $u_i$ infinite time to pass $v_i$.

Comment: That's what you have to show, that's the core of the problem

Comment: We can consider $u_i-v_i$ I guess and say that $\dfrac{d}{dt}(u_i-v_i)\ge 0$ which means $(u_i-v_i)$ is increasing for each $i\le n$. We need to show it goes to zero.  Its because its continous